# Is it bad to have children named with numbers?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a hierarchy of scrapers in my program inheriting from an abstract class named Scraper. Each of its children are assigned to scrape pages differently, but I cannot think of a way to describe their difference in their name. Thus, the children are named Scraper0, Scraper1, ..., ScraperN.

Is this bad practice? If someone read my code would they cry?

Thanks

Comment: i think its bad to have children named with numbers, because theyll have a hard time @school :*

Comment: Catbert says: sometimes we want them to cry.

Comment: Thinking up good names is sometimes very hard. Why don't you post two examples and solicit names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is clearly bad practice - it cries that you can't come up with clear way to describe purpose of the classes. There will be absolutley no way to say if using Scraper1 is wrong in particluar place and Scraper42 should be used insted.

You also can get nick name as "coder3" for such naming :)

Comment: +1 - if the differences in the classes are so small that you can't describe them then the OP has probably gone over the top with OO design, and should have used less classes with a state-machine approach.

Answer (score 2):

It looks bad. Although, in some cases, we can't help but to accept it, If you could help, instead of all those classes which does similar stuff, introduce a single *interface*.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day its up to you, but if each child does something a bit different I would suggest something like ScraperWhatIDoThatsDifferent to give people reading the code more info in the name as to what they are looking at.

If you can make the name more specific, you generally want to do so :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if you couldn't think of names for them if you really tried; but if there's honestly no way to refer to them, I don't think using the numbers is evil or anything.